# install IPK on LG SMART WEBOS TV

Tags: webos, lg

I am trying to permanently install my ipk on LG smart webos tv, or to keep the developer mode still (knowing that it remains activated for 50 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. According to http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/

> Developer Mode is disabled when:
>
> The TV has been rebooted ten times while the TV is not connected to a network (webOS TV v1.x and v2.0).
>
> Developer Mode has been enabled for 50 hours.
>
> The Developer Mode login session is terminated.
>
> If you sign in to multiple TVs with one account, only the session of the latest TV that you sign in to is maintained.
>
> After Developer Mode is disabled, the apps that are installed while you were using on Developer Mode are uninstalled, and you will be taken to the log-in screen of the Developer Mode app.

However, you can keep extending the session time before expiry.
[image: webOS extend time]

Answer (score 5):

If TV have a vulnerable WebOS version, you can access shell console using a root solution.

Check RootMyTv:
https://github.com/RootMyTV/RootMyTV.github.io

Then you can install .ipk package using Device Manager for WebOS:

https://github.com/webosbrew/dev-manager-desktop

You could also try timer reset:

https://webosapp.club/timer/

Check [this](https://webosapp-club.translate.goog/devmode.html?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp) for details.